# After session timeout, a subsequent AJAX post request to the first one will throw InvalidCsrfTokenException

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, spring-security

Please I don’t know how best to construct this question. Permit me to explain the problem.

On my web app, I have a page in which I am using AJAX-based post request to paginate records from database. Changes may be made to the retrieved set of records and updated still by AJAX-based post request. These requests are of type post because of sensitive information that are passed along in each request.

**Problem**

If a user logs in with “remember me” checked. On the AJAX pagination page, if the user for the first time clicks next button to retrieve new set of records after session timeout, it runs successfully. Then, if the user clicks next button again to retrieve another set of records, `InvalidCsrfTokenException` will be thrown causing my custom `AccessDeniedHandler` to redirect the user to login page. I don’t want the user to be redirected to login rather the request should be successful since the remember me cookie is still valid though the HTTP session has expired.
I noticed that when the first AJAX request was made after session time out, a new token value was assign to `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. The subsequent ajax request (second AJAX request) then threw `InvalidCsrfTokenException` because that new token value no longer match the previous CSRF value (i.e. `sec:csrfMetaTags`) on the page that didn't update because the request was AJAX-based.

So please how do I update the page CSRF value (i.e. `sec:csrfMetaTags`) on AJAX request to match `X-XSRF-TOKEN` value? Has spring out-of-the-box solution to this? If no, any better approach to this problem will be so much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you put the CSRF token into a meta tag using Spring security Taglib. This gives you a problem because this is only done once when the page is rendered.

It is very common to have problems with AJAX requests when a session times out, especially when security is involved.

We typically solve this by ensuring that the session does not die. This is done 
by having an endpoint the front-end developer can call, which refreshes the session and tells him when it expires. The front-end calls this endpoint every time the session is close to expiration. If the user computer goes to standby, and the session expires while it is turned of, the front-end will know this when it is powered back on, and it will reload the page so you can get the new CSRF token. If you use a good rooting framework, or local storage you can avoid loosing the user's state.

I would advise against trying to build any workarounds to avoid the page reload. I have seen developers build an endpoint which returns the current CSRF token, and then use JavaScript to update the meta header to avoid reloading the page. This is of cause is a very bad idea, because a hacker can use the endpoint to obtain the token as well. Always be careful with security, there is a reason even big companies get hacked, security is not as simple as it looks.

Answer (score 0):

[`csrfMetaTags`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/taglibs.html#the-csrfmetatags-tag) includes the CSRF token into the page. But the CSRF token is never updated until you reload the page.

> **The csrfMetaTags Tag**
>
> If CSRF protection is enabled, this tag inserts meta tags containing the CSRF protection token form field and header names and CSRF protection token value. These meta tags are useful for employing CSRF protection within JavaScript in your applications.
>
> You should place `csrfMetaTags` within an HTML `<head></head>` block, where you would normally place other meta tags. Once you use this tag, you can access the form field name, header name, and token value easily using JavaScript.

There are some solutions, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-timeouts):

> **Timeouts**
>
> One issue is that the expected CSRF token is stored in the HttpSession, so as soon as the HttpSession expires your configured `AccessDeniedHandler` will receive a InvalidCsrfTokenException. If you are using the default `AccessDeniedHandler`, the browser will get an HTTP 403 and display a poor error message.
>
> [...]
>
> A simple way to mitigate an active user experiencing a timeout is to have some JavaScript that lets the user know their session is about to expire. The user can click a button to continue and refresh the session.
>
> Alternatively, specifying a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` allows you to process the `InvalidCsrfTokenException` any way you like. For an example of how to customize the `AccessDeniedHandler` refer to the provided links for both xml and Java configuration.
>
> Finally, the application can be configured to use `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` which will not expire. As previously mentioned, this is not as secure as using a session, but in many cases can be good enough.